# How to integrate Treant.js in a React projet

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, diagram

I have to use the Treant.js librairy in a React.js project but i have some issues to create diagram. In fact, the official website tell us that we have to import script like that:

```
<script src="vendor/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="Treant.min.js"></script>
```

I don't think that it's possible in react to import scripts like that...
I have also seen that they made a node module ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/treant-js)).
So I installed it and I tryed to import the lib like that

```
import Treant from 'treant-js'
```

Moreover, I have seen in an exemple that they generate diagram like that :

```
<script>
    new Treant( simple_chart_config );
</script>
```

Finally, the import worked but when i try to generate the diagram like that

`{new Treant (this.state.diagram)}`

I have this error : `_treantJs2.default is not a constructor`

Finally I have read this article : [Integrating Treant-js in Angular2 Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43165371/integrating-treant-js-in-angular2-project) and they say to import the lib from the files downloadable from the website but I don't think that it's possible to do that in react...

I already tryed many things but I'm a begginner with react, I'm certainly missing somethin obvious...
If someone have an idea to help me, it would be nice :)
Thank you

**EDIT**

I tryed to import the script directly in the render method of my react component :

```
 render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <script src="../lib/vendor/raphael.js"></script>
        <script src="../lib/Treant.js"></script>
        <script>
            new Treant( {this.state.diagram} );
        </script>
        <p>TEST</p>
      </div>
    )
 }
```

I think that's the good way but I still have this error : 
`Objects are not valid as a React child`

Comment: Don't include the scripts directly into your React components. First I suggest you read up about React and JSX by following a few tutorials. Then you have to understand the stack you are working with, since you are using the `import` syntax you must be working with some kind of module bundler (webpack for instance). Read up on how this works too. Good luck.

Comment: Are you able to get this working

Comment: @Nikhil Mahajan : see my answer below. I have just solved the problem today.

Answer (score 2):

I have been doing research on several free organizational chart libraries. There are some that I tried: orgchart (by dabeng), d3-mitch-tree and Treant.js. I was successful in using the former two in my React app, although only for basic usage.

I just tried hard to do the same with Treant.js. It is not straight-forward. I had to learn quickly about **CommonJs** before working around the problems with Treant.js.
After walking through its source code, I saw that it used CommonJs module system, so its javascript module have to be included using ***require*** statement, not ***import*** statement. You can see my code below.

But, when running the app, it displayed error:

> "Raphael is not defined"

When debugging, I found the cause of the error. Treant.js file depends on ***raphael*** library, which is used in its ***handleOverflow*** function. So I added one line in that function of ***Treant.js*** file to include the dependency as follows:

```
// Create Raphael instance, set scrollbars if necessary
handleOverflow: function(treeWidth, treeHeight) {
    // I added this statement which didn't exist in original file
    var Raphael = require("./vendor/raphael")
    // ...
```

Here is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import "treant-js/Treant.css"
import "treant-js/basic-example.css"

var Treant = require("treant-js/Treant")

export default class MyTreantJs extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.treant = null
    this.chart_config = null
}

componentDidMount() {
    const loginpathname = window.sessionStorage.getItem("appHomePathName", homepathname)
    const index = loginpathname.indexOf("public")
    const homepathname = loginpathname.substring(0,index)
    const imageurl = homepathname + "/public/images/headshots/"

    const config = {
        container: "#basic-example",            
        connectors: {
            type: 'step'
        },
        node: {
            HTMLclass: 'nodeExample1'
        }
    },
    ceo = {
        text: {
            name: "Mark Hill",
            title: "Chief executive officer",
            contact: "Tel: 01 213 123 134",
        },
        image: imageurl + "2.jpg"
    },

    cto = {
        parent: ceo,
        text:{
            name: "Joe Linux",
            title: "Chief Technology Officer",
        },
        stackChildren: true,
        image: imageurl + "1.jpg"
    },
    cbo = {
        parent: ceo,
        stackChildren: true,
        text:{
            name: "Linda May",
            title: "Chief Business Officer",
        },
        image: imageurl + "5.jpg"
    },
    cdo = {
        parent: ceo,
        text:{
            name: "John Green",
            title: "Chief accounting officer",
            contact: "Tel: 01 213 123 134",
        },
        image: imageurl + "6.jpg"
    },
    cio = {
        parent: cto,
        text:{
            name: "Ron Blomquist",
            title: "Chief Information Security Officer"
        },
        image: imageurl + "8.jpg"
    },
    ciso = {
        parent: cto,
        text:{
            name: "Michael Rubin",
            title: "Chief Innovation Officer",
            contact: {val: "we@aregreat.com", href: "mailto:we@aregreat.com"}
        },
        image: imageurl + "9.jpg"
    },
    cio2 = {
        parent: cdo,
        text:{
            name: "Erica Reel",
            title: "Chief Customer Officer"
        },
        link: {
            href: "http://www.google.com"
        },
        image: imageurl + "10.jpg"
    },
    ciso2 = {
        parent: cbo,
        text:{
            name: "Alice Lopez",
            title: "Chief Communications Officer"
        },
        image: imageurl + "7.jpg"
    },
    ciso3 = {
        parent: cbo,
        text:{
            name: "Mary Johnson",
            title: "Chief Brand Officer"
        },
        image: imageurl + "4.jpg"
    },
    ciso4 = {
        parent: cbo,
        text:{
            name: "Kirk Douglas",
            title: "Chief Business Development Officer"
        },
        image: imageurl + "11.jpg"
    }

    this.chart_config = [
        config,
        ceo,
        cto,
        cbo,
        cdo,
        cio,
        ciso,
        cio2,
        ciso2,
        ciso3,
        ciso4
    ];

    this.treant = new Treant(this.chart_config)
}

render(){
  return (
    <div id="basic-example" style={{height:"600px", width:"1200px"}}></div>
  );
}
```

}

Here, the basic-example.css file was copied from the examples folder.
The configuration for the chart was taken from the examples folder too. I used sessionStorage of the browser to find location of the images.
So far, my code worked well.

EDIT :
The above code still doesn't work. **Do not modify the Treant.js source code**. Instead, use the following :

```
import React from "react";
import "treant-js/Treant.css"
import "treant-js/examples/basic-example/basic-example.css"
import Raphael from "raphael";

window.Raphael = Raphael

var Treant = require("treant-js/Treant")
Treant = Treant.Treant
```

Treant doesn't import raphael, but it expects raphael instance to be globally available. That's why after importing raphael in our app we need the statement :

```
window.Raphael = Raphael
```

Notice the statement :

```
Treant = Treant.Treant
```

This is necessary, as Treant (when looking at the console) is an object that has property also named Treant.

Comment: Lex Soft @lex-soft, can you please explain how you integrated d3-mitch-tree into react? I am trying but without success :( thanks!

Comment: @pinker I think it's better to explain it by giving you my code. But I cannot give it in the answers section, whereas this comment section cannot contain the whole code. Maybe by email if you don't mind.

Comment: @pinker I have just created a small app in CodeSandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-tdd-edf73

Comment: Thank you @lex-soft! I will probably create a npm for a react version of this library.

Comment: @pinker It's a pleasure. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this breaks any rules - this might be better as a comment, I honestly don't know, but unfortunately I can't post a comment due to lack of reputation, but really wanted to post an update in case anyone else happens upon this.  The answer above by `Lex Soft` got me almost all the way to the solution, but I had to use the library `treantjs` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/treantjs) instead of `treant-js`.

Basically my imports look like this instead:

```
import 'treantjs/Treant.css';
import Raphael from 'raphael';
import React from 'react';
import Treant from 'treantjs/Treant';

Treant = window.Treant; // this package doesn't load as a module properly...
window.Raphael = Raphael;
```

The `treant-js` library is a little older and is not the official package, so it's not up to date. I specifically was having an issue of the chart only showing the first node when I unmounted the node and mounted a new one.